# Unable to adapt model class into SlingHttpServletRequest

Tags: aem, sling-models

I am trying to inject resources in my model class. Problem I face when I use annotation `@Model(adaptables =  { SlingHttpServletRequest.class, Resource.class })`

I am getting objects as null, whereas with only Resource.Class I am getting the objects (navigationItems). Below is the snippet of my class. Can you let me know the steps to fix it.

```
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Optional;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.List;

@Model(adaptables =  { SlingHttpServletRequest.class, Resource.class })
public class Header {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    @Optional
    @Named("navitems")
    private Resource navigationItems;

    List<SiteNavigation> siteNavigationList;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        logger.info("In init method of header model.");
        siteNavigationList = getSiteNavigationListItems(getNavigationItems());
    }

    private List<SiteNavigation> getSiteNavigationListItems(final Resource navigationItems, final Resource columnFourItems) {
        return null;
    }

    public Resource getNavigationItems() {
        return navigationItems;
    }
}
```

If I remove optional annotation, I am getting below error:

```
28.09.2018 14:04:39.735 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1538123679033] GET /conf/myprj/settings/wcm/templates/homepage/structure.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter Error during include of SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/conf/myprj/settings/wcm/templates/homepage/structure/jcr:content/root/header', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Cannot get DefaultSlingScript: Identifier com.myprj.core.models.Header cannot be correctly instantiated by the Use API
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:510) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.0.54]
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.12]

    Caused by: org.apache.sling.models.factory.MissingElementsException: Could not inject all required fields into class com.myprj.core.models.Header
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:679) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.internalCreateModel(ModelAdapterFactory.java:394) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
    at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createModel(ModelAdapterFactory.java:261) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.models.impl.SlingModelsUseProvider.provide(SlingModelsUseProvider.java:126) [org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.models.provider:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.extension.use.UseRuntimeExtension.call(UseRuntimeExtension.java:73) [org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly:1.0.48.1_3_1]
    ... 243 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.apache.sling.models.factory.MissingElementException: Could not inject private org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource com.myprj.core.models.Header.navigationItems
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:684) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
        ... 247 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.sling.models.factory.ModelClassException: No injector returned a non-null value!
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.injectElement(ModelAdapterFactory.java:581) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
        at org.apache.sling.models.impl.ModelAdapterFactory.createObject(ModelAdapterFactory.java:682) [org.apache.sling.models.impl:1.4.7.T20180205124646-b0647a3]
        ... 247 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does `request.getResource()` provide a wrong resource?

Comment: Added  `@Inject SlingHttpServletRequest request;` in code and `request.getResource()` gives me path of correct node that is header. `/conf/myprj/settings/wcm/templates/homepage/structure/jcr:content/root/header`

Answer (score 1):

3 pointers in your code:

1. While sling9 support multiple adaptables, it is better to [adapt from](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/models/SampleSlingModel.java) SlingHttpServetlRequest object. It is at higher layer and wraps most other objects.
2. It is recommended to make your injector more [specific](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#injector-specific-annotations) than generic @Inject.
3. Always specify [resourceType attribute](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#associating-a-model-class-with-a-resource-type-since-1-3-0-) to associate your model to a specific resource type. Good for exporter of fragments, sling can associate more close and better readability.

This will be my code for your sling model:

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class, resourceType = "myprj/components/content/header",
  defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class Header {

  @ChildResource
  private Resource navitems; // Keeping resource name and attribute name identical reduces @Named annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved with @Via annotation. Below is the snippet I used.

```
@Inject
    @Via("resource")
    @Named("navitems")
    private Resource navigationItems;
```